# Button Border design not showing on simulator

Tags: codenameone

Hi and compliments of the season, I'm designing an interface using GUI Builder. The interface has four buttons. I set the UIID to Button. Now the problem is when i run the app on simulator the button design is not showing. I can only see the text on each button. 
Please kindly help me on this and check the attached picture for more clarification.

[image: Screenshot of both GUI Builder design and Simulator output]

Best Regards,

Yahya-Imam Munir Kolapo

Comment: Did you create the background border yourself or you're using the default codenameone design?

Comment: Thank you Diamond. I'm using codename one default design

Answer (score 1):

In the designer tool menu bar select `Native Theme->iOS->iOS 7`.

[image: Menu]

Buttons won't show in the designer either. iOS 7 style doesn't show button borders (flat design) this was a feature of iOS 6 or older. You can cut your own 9-piece borders as Diamond mentioned.

Comment: Thank you David. I will do as suggested.

Comment: FYI make sure to accept answers that are correct by marking the green V to the left of the answer.